# Why such cotangent space have $dx_i$ instead of $d/dx_i$ as part of their basis?

Tags: differential-geometry, dual-spaces, co-tangent-space

> DEFINTION OF TANGENT BUNDLE:
> Given a smooth manifold $M \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ embedded as a
> hypersurface represented by the vanishing locus of a function $f \in
>  C^{\infty}\left(\mathbb{R}^{n}\right)$ with the condition that $\nabla
>  f \neq 0$, the tangent bundle is
> $$ T M=\left\{(x, v) \in T \mathbb{R}^{n}: f(x)=0, d
> f_{x}(v)=0\right\} $$

My question is since $d f_{x}(v)=\nabla f(x) \cdot v=0$ so doesnt this mean $v=(dx_1,...,dx_{n-1})$ assuming a point in $M$ has the local coordinate representation $(x_1,...,x_{n-1})$. I am writing $v=(dx_1,...,dx_{n-1})$ under the impression that if I expand $\nabla f(x) \cdot v$ I get the form $\sum df/dx_i \cdot dx_i$ and so I have grouped up $dx_i$ to form $v$, since as we know, gradient is perpendicular to the hypersurface so $v$ must be the tangent.

$ \Rightarrow$ $TM$ has the representation $(x_1,...,x_{n-1},dx_1,...,dx_{n-1})$

If this is the case, why do we write the [1-forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-form) which belongs to the space of $T^*M$ as $$\alpha=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \xi_{i} d x_{i}$$ where $\xi_i \in \mathbb{R}$. Shouldn't it be something like $$\alpha=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \xi_{i} \frac{d}{d x_{i}}$$

Where did I go wrong?

---

The idea behind me asking this question is, I understand the [directional derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative) definition of tangent vectors (I might be wrong here), but as soon as I view it from the perspective of my manifold being represented by $f(x)=0$ on some bigger embedding then directional derivative seems to take up a different meaning.

---

Alternatively,

How does one derive that a 1-form can be expressed as  $$\alpha=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \xi_{i} d x_{i}$$

I should add that I am not a vigorous mathematician, so its very likely that I might be defining/interpreting something wrong.

Comment: the $dx^i$ are linear functionals, i.e. linear maps $T_pM\to\mathbb R$, another things are elements of $T_pM$

Comment: the basis elements of the tangent also are interpreted as *derivations* and has the symbol name $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$

Comment: @janmarqz Yes, I am interested in the directional derivative definition of Tangents. My question is since grad . v is zero and since gradient is perpendicular to the surface, shouldn't the tangents be represented by $dx_i$ in this case? Or is there something that I dont see?

Comment: We have that $${\rm grad}f=df=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^1}dx^1+\cdots+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^n}dx^n$$ isn't a tangent vector. It is a linear combination of linear functionals.

Comment: @janmarqz I don't understand. Shouldn't $\nabla f$ be a vector having n components. What you have written is a sum of terms so isnt it a scalar?

Comment: $df$ is linear functional, $\nabla f$ is its Riesz' Representative.

Comment: I am sorry. I have never heard of the the latter. My knowledge was the $df$ is something like $/nabla f \cdot v$ where both are vectors. I would highly appreciate it if you could write something elaborating this in a simple way if possible, whenever you have time. Also, are you saying that in my OP $\nabla f$ itself is the tangent vector OR are you trying to say that the decomposition $\nabla f \cdot v$ is not right?

Comment: Seek for  **Riesz' Representation Theorem** for linear functionals over finite dimensional vector spaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\dd}{\partial}$There's an important distinction between "ambient" and "intrinsic" coordinates. This may not exactly answer your question, but is too long for a comment.

Let's look at the unit circle $M$ as an example:
$$
f(x_{1}, x_{2}) = x_{1}^{2} + x_{2}^{2} - 1 = 0.
$$
Neither ambient coordinate $x_{1}$ or $x_{2}$ is a global coordinate, but at each point of $M$, either $x_{1}$ or $x_{2}$ (or at most points, both) can be used as a local intrinsic coordinate.

Differentiating the preceding equation gives
$$
df(x_{1}, x_{2}) = 2x_{1}\, dx_{1} + 2x_{2}\, dx_{2} = 0.
$$
If $(x_{1}, x_{2})$ is a point of the circle, then a vector $v = (v_{1}, v_{2})$ in the plane is tangent to $M$ at $(x_{1}, x_{2})$ if and only if
$$
df(x_{1}, x_{2}) v = 2x_{1}\, dx_{1}(v) + 2x_{2}\, dx_{2}(v)
= 2x_{1}v_{1} + 2x_{2}v_{2} = 0.
$$
The components of $v$ are not $dx_{1}$ and $dx_{2}$ themselves, but the *values* of these ambient coordinate $1$-forms on $v$. In this example, the vector $v$ is tangent to $M$ at $(x_{1}, x_{2})$ if and only if there is a real number $\lambda$ such that $(v_{1}, v_{2}) = \lambda(-x_{2}, x_{1})$.

What about coordinate vector fields? If we use $x_{1}$ as local coordinate (which we're free to do except at the points $(\pm1, 0)$ where the tangent line is vertical), then in this example $x_{2} = \sqrt{1 - x_{1}^{2}}$ on the upper semi-circle, or $x_{2} = -\sqrt{1 - x_{1}^{2}}$ on the lower semi-circle.

Since $\frac{\dd}{\dd x_{1}}$ has horizontal component $1$, we have $\frac{\dd}{\dd x_{1}} = (1, \mp\frac{x_{1}}{\sqrt{1 - x_{1}^{2}}})$, with the sign chosen depending on location. Every vector field on the circle may be written in an $x_{1}$-coordinate neighborhood as $v_{1}(x_{1})\, \frac{\dd}{\dd x_{1}}$ for some function $v_{1}$, or as $(x_{1}, v_{1}(x_{1}))$. (Note: There is only one summand because the circle is $1$-dimensional, even though there are two ambient coordinates.)

Expressing vector fields in terms of the local coordinate $x_{2}$ (which we may do except at $(0, \pm1)$) is similar.

These manifold coordinates obtained by restricting ambient coordinates are not especially elegant, but the point is to illustrate how coordinate notation works in this situation.

Comment: Belated, but this is what I was about to post in response to the [earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4179686/)....

Comment: Ohh okay so my mistake was decomposing $df$ directly to the form $\nabla f \cdot v$. I think this is what @Janmarqz also meant to say in his comments, although I didnt understand that. Thank you so much and sorry for deleting the previous question, I thought it was unclear or something so thought I should try and restructure it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

It's really all just choices of notation, so you have to be very explicit with your notation. However, you have a totally valid confusion here, and this is a common issue people have with the gradient.

Technically $\nabla f$ is a **vector field**, not a $1$-form, so it doesn't actually make sense to apply $\nabla f$ to a tangent vector. However, we can still take the dot product $\nabla f\cdot v$. It only makes sense to take dot products with vectors in the same vector space, so actually the basis vectors of $\nabla f$ and $v$ should be the same.

To make this more natural, we really want to use $df$, which is dual to $\nabla f$. In coordinates, $\nabla f$ is a column vector, while $df$ is a row vector. We can then apply $df$ to a tangent vector, and this corresponds to multiplying a $1\times n$ matrix with an $n\times 1$ matrix. So the basis of $df$ should be dual to that of $v$.

Comment: Could you please explain this a bit more: "It only makes sense to take dot products with vectors in the same vector space, so actually the basis vectors of $\nabla f$ and $v$ should be the same." My whole argument was under the assumption that $\nabla f \cdot v$ is a dual space mapping since it takes a vector $\nabla f$ to a scalar. Also, in the situation that I have presented wouldn't it be safe to assume that the tangent vectors are spanned by $dx_i$, since gradient is perpendicular to the surface?

Comment: "It only makes sense to take dot products between a vector and a covector (or more carefully, an element of a vector space and an element of that vector space's dual)."  Fixed that for you.  The abuse of notation of dot product among pairs of vectors in a Euclidean vector space is an accident of (noncanonical) isomorphism between a Euclidean vector space and its dual.

Comment: @Eric I would disagree; to me a dot product is a bilinear form on a vector space. The gradient *isn't* natural for general smooth manifolds. Of course for finite dimensions identifying $V$ with $V^*$ is the same as a choice of basis anyway.

Comment: @EricTowers.. Okay... so in my case, is it alright to say that $\nabla f$ and $v$ are dual to each other? Also, I am aware that $\nabla$ is a one-form, is $\nabla f$ for some scalar function $f$, too a one-form?

Comment: $\nabla f$ is a vector field

Comment: @ElliotG I am a physicst, so I might be completely off with standard math definitions. My understanding of dual spaces is through the dual mapping that takes one vector to a scalar number (in its field). If this is right, wouldn't it be safe to assume that two vectors defined through an inner product are dual to each other? I mean the inner product seems to satisfy the dual mapping which is Hom$(V,F)$ where F is the field of vector space V.

Comment: it isn't @ElliotG

Comment: @janmarqz I guess it is non-standard. The gradient is a vector field according to Lee (and wikipedia), but a $1$-form according to Bott & Tu. Or rather, Bott & Tu refer to $df$ as "the gradient of $f$" but also define $\nabla f$ as a vector field.

Comment: wikipedia isn't a trustworthy source of information

Comment: Ok I don't really see the point arguing this, but $\nabla f$ is a vector field according to Lee, Bott & Tu, Guillemin & Pollack, and Audin & Damian. With a choice of metric you can identify a vector field with a $1$-form, so it often doesn't matter.

Comment: @janmarqz based on the above comment by ElliotG, is it the case that $\nabla$ is a one-form while $\nabla f$ isn't and is just a vector field?

Comment: it seems he does consider nothing about the Riesz' Representation Thm.